# gpg --quick-generate-key user-id [algo [usage [expire]]] - Any way to include a comment?

Tags: gnupg, key-generation

I am doing some unattended key generation using `--quick-gen-key` and `--quick-add-key`.  I am not clear if the `user-id` mentioned in the `man` page offers a way to include a comment:

```
--quick-generate-key user-id [algo [usage [expire]]]
```

I usually see this used as "My Name My@email.com".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to work like this:

```
gpg --quick-generate-key "MyName (MyComment) <my@email.com>" rsa1024 cert never
```

At least, when you do it that way, the `--list-keys` output appears the same as that produced by a key generated with  `--full-generate-key`, which individually prompts for Name/eMail/Comment to create the UID field.